# Difference between these joins

Tags: sql, join

Is there any difference between

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A a
JOIN TABLE_B b
  ON a.propertyA = b.propertyA
```

And the query

```
SELECT * from TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b where a.propertyA=b.propertyA.
```

Comment: The second is still considered a "join", but it's the old-school version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` is ANSI (*SQL-92*) syntax which you use on the first one. It is generally considered more readable, especially when you join lots of tables.

The `WHERE syntax` (*SQL-89*) is more relational model oriented. A result of two tables JOIN'ed is a cartesian product of the tables to which a filter is applied which selects only those rows with joining columns matching.

It's easier to see this with the WHERE syntax.

I'd rather go on the `ANSI` type join because if you some how omit the `ON` clause, an error is generated whereas the  old type of join if you omit the condition on `where` clause will not produce an error message and thus it will generate cartesian product.

Comment: +1 for nice explanation, would be great if you could add links to the documentation for ANSI(SQL-92) and (SQL-89)

Answer (score 2):

The two examples are the same. Both perform an INNER JOIN operation (even if it's just JOIN in the 2nd example) which basically returns all rows that contain matching results in relation to the ON clause.

My guess is that the JOIN and INNER JOIN operations are just a bit faster since they're designed for that specific purpose while SELECT statements can be modified around to do much more.

Answer (score 0):

The "join" version has been around about 20 years and is preferred because it clearly identifies predicates used for the join as opposed to those used for filtering results.
It also allow outer joins if used with `left join` (where you still get table_a's row if there isn't a matching row in table_b).

The "comma" version doesn't allow outer joins (you won't get table_a's row if there isn't a matching row in table_b)